# How much cheaper will Bitcoin transaction fees be when Taproot is implemented in November of 2021?

Tags: transaction-fees, taproot

With the upcoming taproot upgrade to the network. How much cheaper will fees for sending a transaction? If not, are there other improvement proposals to reduce fees?

Comment: Not a full answer, but perhaps helps avoid a misconception: what matters isn't the activation of taproot, but when you switch/update to a wallet that makes use of it. And how much is gained very much depends on what your wallet does, and how it changes. Most gains will be seen in multisig wallets, or other things that use more complex scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/106933/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105884/5406